# in R, custom return value based on specific warning

Tags: r, error-handling

I have kind of a strange case where I'm trying to look for a specific warning and return one thing if I see it and a different thing if I don't. I feel like I must be missing something, but I can't figure out how to do it, at least not without calling the originating function twice. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

The specific case is: I'm reading in files with `data.table::fread()` and, if I see a specific parsing warning, I want to return `NULL` instead of the (incorrectly) parsed data.

Below are my first three attempts, and some tests to prove the issue with them. Note that `my_func3` actually passes all the tests, but requires reading in all the data *twice*. Obviously, in my real application, the data is much larger and hence this is definitely *not* ideal.

```r
# this one fails test 3
# because it doesn't return anything if _any_ warning is caught
my_func1 <- function(.string) {
  res <- tryCatch(
    {
      data.table::fread(text = .string)
    },
    warning = function(.w) {
      if (grepl("Stopped early.+TABLE NO", .w$message)) {
        warning("my custom warning")
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        warning(.w)
      }
    }
  )
}

# this one fails test 2
# because it returns the parsed df even if we catch the custom warning
my_func2 <- function(.string) {
  res <- withCallingHandlers(
    {
      data.table::fread(text = .string)
    },
    warning = function(.w) {
      if (grepl("Stopped early.+TABLE NO", .w$message)) {
        warning("my custom warning")
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        warning(.w)
      }
    }
  )
}


# this one passes all three
# but it requires reading the data twice
my_func3 <- function(.string) {
  res <- tryCatch(
    {
      data.table::fread(text = .string)
    },
    warning = function(.w) {
      if (grepl("Stopped early.+TABLE NO", .w$message)) {
        warning("my custom warning")
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        data.table::fread(text = .string)
      }
    }
  )
}



##################
# TESTS
##################

# uncomment the one you want to test
#my_func <- my_func1
#my_func <- my_func2
#my_func <- my_func3

library(testthat)

test_that("test 1: my_func returns df when no warning", {
  df <- my_func("a,b\n1,2\n3,4")
  expect_equal(nrow(df), 2)
  expect_equal(ncol(df), 2)
})

test_that("test 2: my_func warns and returns NULL on custom warning", {
  expect_warning(
    df <- my_func("a,b\n1,2\nTABLE NO\n3,4"),
    regexp = "my custom warning"
  )
  expect_null(df)
})

test_that("test 3: my_func warns and returns df on other warning ", {
  expect_warning(
    df <- my_func("a,b\n1,2,3\n")
  )
  expect_equal(nrow(df), 1)
  expect_equal(ncol(df), 3)
})
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this *without* having to read the data twice are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got an answer from a colleague. It is below, using the much simpler `warning_prone_function()` example courtesy of @allan-cameron.

The key here is to pass our custom warning back up to the enclosing environment with `<<-` and then check it before we return from `my_func`. Then we raise any other warning we may have gotten, and continue through with `invokeRestart("muffleWarning")`. (The `muffleWarning` parts prevent it from raising the same warning again when we restart. I'm *pretty sure* this doesn't cause `warning_prone_function()` to get called again, but to be honest, the `invokeRestart` docs baffle me a little bit, so I may be wrong. Either way, see note below about a way to do this without `invokeRestart`, if necessary.

Hope this is helpful for someone. Thanks for @allan-cameron.

```r
warning_prone_function <- function(.string) {
  num <- as.numeric(.string)
  num <- num[!is.na(num)]
  cor(seq_along(num), num)
}


my_func <- function(.string) {
  W <- NULL
  res <- withCallingHandlers(
    {
      warning_prone_function(.string)
    },
    warning = function(.w) {
      if (grepl("coercion", .w$message)) {
        W <<- "Some strings were not numbers"
      } else {
        warning(.w)
      }
      invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    }
  )
  
  if (!is.null(W)) {
    warning(W)
    res <- NULL
  }
  
  return(res)
}

###############
# TESTS
###############

library(testthat)

test_that("test 1: my_func returns df when no warning", {
  res <- my_func(c("1", "2", "3"))
  expect_equal(res, 1)
})

test_that("test 2: my_func warns and returns NULL on custom warning", {
  expect_warning(
    res <- my_func(c("a", "b", "c")),
    regexp = "Some strings were not numbers"
  )
  expect_null(res)
})

test_that("test 3: my_func warns and returns res on other warning ", {
  expect_warning(
    res <- my_func(c("1", "1", "1")),
    "standard deviation"
  )
  expect_true(is.na(res))
})
```

*NOTE:* technically, the tests pass if you remove the `else` block and the `invokeRestart` section:

```r
        else {
        warning(.w)
      }
      invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
```

However, removing these causes the original `"coercion"` warning *and* your custom warning to both be raised. Using it as written above suppresses the `"coercion"` warning, which was my original intent (though not stated in the OP).

Comment: This is a nice exposition, though doesn't the `invokeRestart` also just cause the function to run twice, which you were trying to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `fread` doesn't lend itself well to a reproducible example, so let's create another warning-prone function:

```r
warning_prone_function <- function(.string)
{
    num <- as.numeric(.string)
    num <- num[!is.na(num)]
    cor(seq_along(num), num)
}
```

This function will easily produce 2 different warnings: one if NAs are produced in coercion from strings to numbers, and a different one if all strings are the same number.

```r
# Input OK - no warning
warning_prone_function(c("1", "2", "3"))
#> [1] 1

# Input produces standard deviation warning
warning_prone_function(c("1", "1", "1"))
#> Warning in cor(seq_along(num), num): the standard deviation is zero
#> [1] NA

# Input produces coercion warning
warning_prone_function(c("a", "b", "c"))
#> Warning in warning_prone_function(c("a", "b", "c")): NAs introduced by coercion
#> [1] NA
```

Now let's wrap our function in a warning handler that gives a custom warning and returns `NULL` if there is coercion, but in other cases behaves the same as `warning_prone_function`

```
my_func <- function(.string) {

  res <- tryCatch(
    {
      warning_prone_function(.string)
    },
    warning = function(.w) {
      if (grepl("coercion", .w$message)) {
        warning("Some strings were not numbers")
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        warning_prone_function(.string)
      }
    }
  )
  res
}
```

So, testing the same inputs, we get:

```
my_func(c("1", "2", "3"))
#> [1] 1

my_func(c("1", "1", "1"))
#> Warning in cor(seq_along(num), num): the standard deviation is zero
#> [1] NA

my_func(c("a", "b", "c"))
#> Warning in value[[3L]](cond): Some strings were not numbers
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for setting up a better example. The problem is: you're example is the same as `my_func3` above, in that it succeeds by calling `warning_prone_function` a second time. This is not ideal because, in my actual use case, this would involve reading the entire (sometimes large) file _twice_. If this is the only option then I guess I'll just have to take the performance hit, but it seems very unfortunate to double the run time of the function.